# Show parts of the page with ng-show like virginamerica website

Tags: angularjs, partials, ng-show

in my project i've to do something very similar to virginamerica.com ux logic. 
I've to set my page in 3 parts, and set them visible depending on the routeParams. So, imagine this:

- A list of items [visible on the root]
- Detail of the item with some variations [visible on the root/item]
- Item editor page [visible on the root/item/var]

I'm trying to set up an angular application to do this, but i've some problems, i'm doing something like this:

- in my index.html i've this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="box">

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Box loader</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="box.js"></script>
    <!-- <base href="/"> -->
</head>

<body ng-controller="boxCtrl">
<section id="box-chooser">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="box in boxes">
            <a href="#/{{box.boxid}}">{{box.boxname}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
<div ng-show="detailVisible">
<section ng-controller="boxDetailCtrl">

    <h1>detail {{boxcode}}</h1>

</section>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

- this is the angularjs part:

```js
var app = angular.module('box', []);

app.config(function($routeProvider /*$locationProvider*/) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {} )
        .when('/:boxid', {


        })

    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});


app.controller('boxCtrl', function($scope, $route, $location) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        var path = $location.path();
        console.log(path);
        $scope.detailVisible = false;
        if(path === '/123') {

            $scope.detailVisible= true;
        }
    });

    $scope.boxes = [{'boxid':'123', 'boxname': 'name1'}, {'boxid':'189', 'boxname': 'name2'}, {'boxid':'156', 'boxname': 'name3'}]

});

app.controller('boxDetailCtrl', function($scope, $route, $location){

    $scope.boxcode = $location.path();


    console.log('secondo:' + $location.path())


});
```

Problem is that boxcode on the second controller works only after a page refresh on localhost/#/123 and ng-show works on the path change.

Any better idea to doing this? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you familiar with using directives?

Comment: Hi @Rorschach120 i'm starting with angularjs in these days, i've followed a couple of tutorial on directives, what can i do with that?

Comment: You should create a 'box-item' directive that is used to display your box items and include the details and toggling behavior you are looking for.

Comment: seems like actually the only way to solve this is to use ui-router..